# After moving the recusion code to the Zend Framework, does not works poperly

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

First some code, question at the end of my post. My code generates list li ul from DB:

Sample SQL:

```
   CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  `gallery` (
  `idgallery` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `parent` varchar(45) DEFAULT '0',
  `type` varchar(45) DEFAULT 'category',
  `menu` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idgallery`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `gallery` (`idgallery`, `name`, `parent`, `type`, `menu`) VALUES
(1, 'Gallery', '0', 'Gallery', ''),
(2, 'Name', '1', 'category', ''),
(3, 'Name2', '0', 'category', ''),
(4, 'Name3', '3', 'category', ''),
(5, 'qwerty', '4', 'category', ''),
(6, 'child', '3', 'category', ''),
(7, 'child', '1', 'category', '');
```

This code works well before moving to ZendFW:

```
$ro=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM gallery");
$rows=array();

while($rowek=mysql_fetch_object($ro))
{
 $rows[]=$rowek;
} 

echo mapTree($rows,0,"category");

function children($rows, $id) {
foreach ($rows as $row) {
if ($row->parent == $id)
return true;
}
return false;
}

function mapTree($rows, $parent = 0, $class = "none") {
$result = "<ul>";
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    if ($row->parent == $parent) {
    $result.= "<li class='$class'>$row->name";
        if (children($rows, $row->idgallery))
        $result.= mapTree($rows, $row->idgallery, "category");
    $result.= "</li> ";
    }
}
$result.= "</ul>";

return $result;
}
```

And in Zend FW i'm using Action Helper. *All object DB is passed to my helper (error_log), but it is only showing:*

```
Gallery
      Name
```

Two records in good order/styling... but where is another 5?

**Index Action:**

```
    //preDispatch()
    Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::addPath(APPLICATION_PATH .'/controllers/helpers');
    //IndexAction()
    $gallery = new Application_Model_DbTable_Gallery;

    $request = $gallery->fetchAll($gallery->select()->order("parent"));

    $helper = $this->_helper->gallery->index($request);

    $this->view->gallery = $helper;
```

**Action Helper**

```
class Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_Gallery extends Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_Abstract{

function index($rows){
    echo $this->mapTree($rows,0,"");
}

function children($rows, $id) {
foreach ($rows as $row) {
if ($row->parent == $id)
return true;
}
return false;
}

function mapTree($rows, $parent = 0, $class = "brak") {
$result = "<ul>";
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    if ($row->parent == $parent) {
    $result.= "<li class='$class'>$row->name";
        if ($this->children($rows, $row->idgallery))
        $result.= $this->mapTree($rows, $row->idgallery, "category");
    $result.= "</li> ";
    }
}
$result.= "</ul>";

return $result;
}

}
```

**And also view...**

```
<?php $this->gallery;?>
```

**My question is - why my code in ZF can't be finished?**

Answer (score 0):

> Two records in good order/styling... but where is another 5?

Your function did what you told it to and processed just those rows with the parent of '0':
`if ($row->parent == $parent)` and `echo $this->mapTree($rows,0,"");`

If you intend for '0' to mean false or null, as it appears you do, you may wish to rethink how you implement that piece of functionality.

As with [View helpers](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.view.helpers.html) in Zend Framework, [Action helpers](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.actionhelpers.html#zend.controller.actionhelper.writingyourown) seem to work best when a value is returned. In this case you may also wish to implement `direct()` so you won't have to call `->index()` everytime:

```
class Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_Gallery extends Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_Abstract
{    
    //we're using php 5, visibility matters
    public function direct($rows){
        return $this->mapTree($rows,0,"");
    }
    protected function children($rows, $id) {
    //truncated
    }
    protected function mapTree($rows, $parent = 0, $class = "brak") {
    //truncated
    }
}
```

now when you call this action helper:

```
 $helper = $this->_helper->gallery($request);
```

Your view needs a fix as well:

```
<!-- remember to 'echo' everything in the view -->
<?php echo $this->gallery;?>
```

As to exactly why your old code works and the the ZF does not work, I can't say. I suspect however that much of the problem will be in the differences between the *Mysql* functions in the old code and either the *Mysqli* or *PDO* database adapter in Zend Framework.